# Callback in Native Messaging

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, callback, chrome-native-messaging

I have a native app in Java and a Chrome extension.
A round trip of my application is like this:

1. JavaScript initiates a call to Native App.
2. Native app reads the stream and does some calculations.
3. Native app needs to call a JS function and needs its result for some further calculations.
4. If the native app calls JS (by sending a message via the extension), then what happens?

I know that I call call a callback by JS later when the call is done, but how can I wait here on Java side to get the result back? Previously I had an Applet and used to use FutureTask object, but do you think it would be here also possible to create a FutureTask?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Just add some code then we can find any errors or further steps.Using Selenium web driver it's Possible.

Answer (score 0):

When your process requires more than one message from JS to the native app (and back), a simple solution is to include a transaction request and a transaction identifier to allow the continuity of different tasks. So, your native app in Java wont be "waiting" for the second message specifically, but will be waiting for any message. It simply will be able to tell if the received message is a continuation from a previous message or if it's a new one.

For example

1. From JS to Native app, the JSON message could be something like:

   {"transaction_id":"123","request":"give_me_your_name"}
2. Native app's response to JS:

   {"transaction_id":"123","response":"john"}
3. JS consecutive request to native app:

   {"transaction_id":"123","request":"do_something"}
4. Native app's response to JS:

   {"transaction_id":"123","response":"ok"}

Your JS and Native app code will need to act accordingly to the requests and responses for a given transaction_id.